# How to share app info on facebook through iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, status

Okay, perhaps it has been asked before, don't flame me if it has by posting a billion links. 
If the user likes my iPhone app, I'd like them to click a button on my app which would allow them to post a status on their facebook wall with an image or a link.

Note: I am not asking how to post a status on a FB Wall through an iPhone app. I want the text already filled out in the status content. I'm delegating how marketing of my app to the user, so if the user likes the app, he can click "Share app info on FB" which would allow him to post an FB status that is filled out by promotion ploys like "Woah, check this app out, it's awesome!" .

Now that you know what my intention is, please suggest me ways to do this with useful links pertaining to the how-to aspect. I'm not particular on how it's done but the logic is:

iPhone app->IBaction-> leads to FB status message with filled out text and link .

Now please use your creative thinking to help!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that you shall actually search more, but I found it for you.

That `IBAction` shall push a WebView that redirects to:

```
"sharer.php", with parameters "u" and "t"
```

The URL format is as follows (giving the example of CNN.com, wrapping for ease of viewing):

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php

?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F

&t=CNN%26s+website
```

Hope I helped!

Source: http://askville.amazon.com/add-Share-Facebook-button-webpage/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1539369

Comment: I would normally recommend that you **not** try to manually wrap text in your answers.  For things like code, or URLs, I would use the **"{ }"** button to format them as code (also achieved by simply indenting with 4 spaces).  This will create a scrollbar.  Viewers can then copy and paste the URL you're sharing, without having to splice it back together.  Just a recommendation.